# Calculate some numbers entered by users in Edit Text in android

Tags: android

I am creating a BMI calculator. There will be two edit text. One will be of Height and one will be of weight. There will be a calculate button. On clicking that, i want that the weight is divided by height which will be again divided by height. i.e. weight/height/height.

```
package com.dibdev.bmicalculator;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class CalBmi extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cal_bmi);

    EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
    EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);
}

}
```

Comment: Get value from EditText using getText() and convert it long or double as per your requirement and then simple do divide operation.

Comment: @HareshChhelana What do you mean by that?
I am a beginner in programming so please explain. :)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class CalBmi extends Activity {

    private EditText et1;
    private EditText et2;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cal_bmi);

        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
        et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);
        button = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(et1.getText().toString().trim().length()<=0){
                et1.setError("Value Required");
            }
            if(et2.getText().toString().trim().length()<=0){
                et2.setError("Value Required");
            }
            if(et1.getText().toString().trim().length()>0 && et2.getText().toString().trim().length()>0){
                Double bmi = Double.parseDouble(et1.getText().toString())/(Double.parseDouble(et2.getText().toString())*2); 
                if(bmi < 25 ){
                    Toast.makeText(CalBmi.this,"your are underweight",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if(bmi >= 25 && bmi <= 50){
                    Toast.makeText(CalBmi.this,"you are normal",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am able to do it properly

Comment: @DibyamKumar,okay good luck,if my ans help you to solve your problem then you can accept it.

Comment: Just tell me that how can i print some thing like this
if bmi is less that 25 print your are underweight and if bmi is between 25 and 50, you are normal

Comment: @DibyamKumar,Best Of Luck For Bright Future and im android developer last 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. hope its help. and give some time to read this clearly https://developer.android.com/training/index.html

```
    package com.dibdev.bmicalculator;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class CalBmi extends Activity {


    Double etxt1,etxt2,result;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cal_bmi);

        EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
        EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);
        Button calculate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.buttonid);
        calculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   try {
                    String ET1 = ET1.getText().toString();  
                    String ET2 = ET2.getText().toString();
                    etxt1= Double.parseDouble(ET1);
                    etxt2= Double.parseDouble(ET2);
                    result=etxt1/etxt2;
                    Toast.makeText(CalBmi.this,
                                        "BMI:" +result,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
              } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

              }
        });
    }

    }
```

Comment: @Dibyam i think you should get some time to android tutorial.. first know how code works and then start your app. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cal_bmi);

    final EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
    final EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);

    Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            double double1 = Double.parseDouble(et1.getText().toString());
            double double2 = Double.parseDouble(et2.getText().toString());
            double res=double1/double2/double2; 
        }
    });
}
```